# Cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate SuppressWarningsHolder

Tags: maven, checkstyle

I have maven-checkstyle-plugin(v2.5) and maven-eclipse-plugin(v2.8) configured.

Everything worked as expected but as soon as I introduced,

*module name="SuppressWarningsHolder"* **AND/OR** *module name="SuppressWarningsFilter"* 
to my checkstyle-config.xml, I started to have problems building the project.

Here is what I get:

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
1>  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
1>  [INFO] Failed during checkstyle configuration
1>  
1>EXEC : Embedded error : cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate SuppressWarningsHolder
1>  Unable to instantiate SuppressWarningsHolderCheck
```

If I remove SuppressWarningsHolderCheck, I get the same error for SuppressWarningsFilter.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears you have two problems:

- You are using [maven-checkstyle-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/) v2.5, which is based on Checkstyle 5.0. In Checkstyle 5.0, the SuppressWarningsHolderCheck and the SuppressWarningsFilter did not exist yet, as they were introduced in 5.7. So you must first upgrade your maven-checkstyle-plugin.
- The [SuppressWarningsFilter](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html#SuppressWarningsFilter) must be configured directly under `Checker`, not under `TreeWalker`. The documentation does not make that part very explicit, although it is there. Note that the SuppressWarnings*Holder* *does* go under `TreeWalker`.

If you do both things, stuff should hopefully start working.

Comment: I just changed maven-checkstyle-plugin version to 2.8 and moved <module name="SuppressWarningsFilter"/> right under Checker. Still getting the same problem.

Comment: What is version 2.8 based on? Is there a link were I can see this info? Thanks

Comment: 2.8 is based on 5.4, so yes, still not good enough. I found the information [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin); click on the version number, then look under *Checkstyle*.

Comment: FYI, the [Checkstyle Compatibility Matrix](http://checkstyle-addons.thomasjensen.com/checkstyle-compatibility-matrix.html) shows which versions exactly are compatible, including the Maven Checkstyle plugin.